# How To Call 'Name' Tag In JS With 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very confused on how this works:

```
$(this).val()
```

It seems to be returning the `value` in a HTML tag. How could I make this return the `name` tag?

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and repays you that time almost immediately.

Comment: Side note: `name` is an *attribute* of an *element*. "Tags" are the written things in HTML that get turned into elements in the DOM by the browser when it parses the HTML text. You don't "call" attributes (or tags, or elements), you "use" or "get" or "access" them. You "call" functions and such. (Not giving you a hard time, just giving you the vocabulary that helps you find help in the future.)

Comment: Ya because `the name tag` would more refers to `this.tagName`, this is at least how i read the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `this` is a node or jQuery object:

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
    $(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the element being acted upon is often passed to the function parameter of a jQuery function as this. It can be made into a jQuery element object by using $(this) in the function parameter, ex:

```
$('.menu a').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({paddingLeft: $(this).width()}, 200);
});
```

Font: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?42053-jQuery-%28this%29-usage

If you have this code:

```
$("#someItem").click(function(){
      $(this) -> returns $("#someItem");
});
```

If you want the name attribute, try:

```
$(this).attr("name");
```